# How to benchmark this correctly

Tags: c++, visual-studio, optimization, benchmarking

I'm trying to benchmark a calculation against the lookup table of the same calculation, but I suspect that at release time, the compiler is reporting inaccurate data.

I benchmark as debug, and then as release

- the lookup table of a single random point
- the entire lookup table within a for loop
- direct calculation
- direct calculation of the entire table
  .

'''

```
Lookup table took 0.1099 seconds to execute

Lookup entire table took 663.521 seconds to execute

Calculation took 0.2698 seconds to execute

Calculation of entire table took 1804.6 seconds to execute
```

'''

then I benchmark all, again, as release, with -O2 optimization

```
Lookup table took 0.0005 seconds to execute

Lookup entire table took 0.0003 seconds to execute

Calculation took 0.098 seconds to execute

Calculation of entire table took 422.066 seconds to execute
```

when debugging, the lookup table is 4/5 times faster, but at release, is hundreds of times faster, so I suspect that I'm wrongly benchmarking the direct calculation.
This is the direct calculation:

```
igc__blade1 = blade1 >> 1u;
igc__blade1 ^= igc__blade1 >> 1u;
igc__blade1 ^= igc__blade1 >> 2u;
igc__blade1 ^= igc__blade1 >> 4u;

blade2__masked = igc__blade1 & blade2;
//__builtin_popcount replaces commented text
parity__2 = __builtin_popcount(blade2__masked & 0b11111110) & 1u;
/*parity__2 = blade2__masked;
    parity__2 ^= parity__2 >> 1u;
    parity__2 ^= parity__2 >> 2u;
    parity__2 ^= parity__2 >> 4u;
    parity__2 = parity__2 & 2u;*/

sign_of_product = 1 - 2 * parity__2;
//sign_of_product = 1 - parity__2;
```

and this is the lookup table call

```
sign_of_product = lookup_table_sign[row][col];
```

**As I understand, a lookup table fetch from L1 cache takes in the order of 10 clock cycles, and my entire code uses 15/20 instructions (`XOR`, `AND`, arithmetic), (and I replaced half of it with a `popcount` instruction).

So the direct calculation, especially after compiling with -O2 optimization, should take at most double the time of the table lookup, not hundreds of times.

I'm doing something wrong, and I don't know what.

I'm suspect that the compiler understands that the for loop only ends with the final calculation, and cuts the entire nested loop, fetching only the last value, but I have no way to know what is going on**

this is the full code

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <bitset>
#include <chrono>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdint.h>
#ifdef _MSC_VER
#include <intrin.h>
#define __builtin_popcount __popcnt
#endif

using namespace std;

long long REPETITIONS = 10000;

int64_t inverseGrayCode(int64_t n)
{
    n ^= n >> 1;
    n ^= n >> 2;
    n ^= n >> 4;
    n ^= n >> 8;  // unnecessary for 8 bit unsigned integers
    n ^= n >> 16; // unnecessary for 16 bit unsigned integers
    n ^= n >> 32; // unnecessary for 32 bit unsigned integers
    return n;
}

const uint8_t BITS = 6;
const uint8_t SIZE = 0b1 << (BITS);
uint8_t blades[SIZE];
uint8_t igc_blades[SIZE];
uint8_t abs_blades_product[SIZE][SIZE];
uint8_t blades_masked[SIZE][SIZE];
uint8_t parity_2[SIZE][SIZE];
int8_t sign[SIZE][SIZE];
int8_t (*lookup_table_sign)[SIZE];

#pragma region lexicographical
uint64_t _64INDIVIDUAL_BIT[SIZE];
double WEIGHT[SIZE];
void initialize_constants()
{
    uint64_t one = 1;
    for (uint64_t x = 0; x < 64; x++)
    {
        _64INDIVIDUAL_BIT[x] = one << x;
        WEIGHT[x] = pow(2.0, -(1 + (double)x));
    }
}
// Function to calculate the lexicographical weight of an integer
double lexicographical_weight(uint64_t x)
{
    double weight = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++)
    {
        weight += ((x & _64INDIVIDUAL_BIT[i]) > 0) * WEIGHT[i];
    }
    return __builtin_popcount(x) + 1 - weight;
}
bool compareByWeight(int element1, int element2)
{
    return lexicographical_weight(element1) < lexicographical_weight(element2);
}

#pragma endregion lexicographical

int8_t (*calc_blade_products(uint8_t blades[]))[SIZE]
{
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        igc_blades[i] = inverseGrayCode(blades[i] >> 1);
    }

    for (int row = 0; row < SIZE; row++)
    {

        for (int col = 0; col < SIZE; col++)
        {
            abs_blades_product[row][col] = blades[row] ^ blades[col];
            blades_masked[row][col] = igc_blades[row] & blades[col];
            // aux[i][j] = inverseGrayCode(blades_masked[i][j]);
            parity_2[row][col] = inverseGrayCode(blades_masked[row][col]) & 2u;
            sign[row][col] = 1 - parity_2[row][col];
        }
    }
    return sign;
}

uint8_t igc__blade1;
uint8_t blade2__masked;
uint8_t parity__2;
int8_t sign_of_product;
uint8_t blade1;
uint8_t blade2;

int main()
{
    initialize_constants();

#pragma region generate_blades_in_lexicographical_order

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        blades[i] = i << 1;
        // fprintf(stdout, "blade %d: %8sb\n", i, bitset<8>(blades[i]).to_string().c_str());
    }
    blades[0] = 1;

    int arraySize = sizeof(blades) / sizeof(blades[0]);
    sort(blades, blades + arraySize, compareByWeight);

#pragma endregion generate_blades_in_lexicographical_order

    // Create lookup_table
    lookup_table_sign = calc_blade_products(blades);

#pragma region benchmark
    uint8_t blade1 = rand() % 256;
    uint8_t blade2 = rand() % 256;

    // benchmark single point with table lookup
    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    for (int rept = 0; rept < REPETITIONS; rept++)
    {
        sign_of_product = lookup_table_sign[blade1][blade2];
    }
    auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli> elapsed_miliseconds = end - start;

    cout << endl;
    cout << "Lookup table took " << elapsed_miliseconds.count() << " seconds to execute" << endl;

    start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    // benchmark entire table with table lookup
    for (int rept = 0; rept < REPETITIONS; rept++)
    {
        for (int row = 0; row < SIZE; row++)
        {
            for (int col = 0; col < SIZE; col++)
            {
                sign_of_product = lookup_table_sign[row][col];
            }
        }
    }
    end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    elapsed_miliseconds = end - start;

    cout << endl;
    cout << "Lookup entire table took " << elapsed_miliseconds.count() << " seconds to execute" << endl;

    // benchmark single point with direct calculation
    start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    for (int rept = 0; rept < REPETITIONS; rept++)
    {
        igc__blade1 = blade1 >> 1u;
        igc__blade1 ^= igc__blade1 >> 1u;
        igc__blade1 ^= igc__blade1 >> 2u;
        igc__blade1 ^= igc__blade1 >> 4u;

        blade2__masked = igc__blade1 & blade2;
        //__builtin_popcount replaces commented text
        parity__2 = __builtin_popcount(blade2__masked & 0b11111110) & 1u;
        /*parity__2 = blade2__masked;
         parity__2 ^= parity__2 >> 1u;
         parity__2 ^= parity__2 >> 2u;
         parity__2 ^= parity__2 >> 4u;
         parity__2 = parity__2 & 2u;*/

        sign_of_product = 1 - 2 * parity__2;
        // sign_of_product = 1 - parity__2;
    }
    end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    elapsed_miliseconds = end - start;

    cout << endl;
    cout << "Calculation took " << elapsed_miliseconds.count() << " seconds to execute" << endl;

    // benchmark entire table with direct calculation
    start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    for (int rept = 0; rept < REPETITIONS; rept++)
    {
        for (int blade1 = 0; blade1 < SIZE; blade1++)
        {
            for (int blade2 = 0; blade2 < SIZE; blade2++)
            {
                igc__blade1 = blade1 >> 1u;
                igc__blade1 ^= igc__blade1 >> 1u;
                igc__blade1 ^= igc__blade1 >> 2u;
                igc__blade1 ^= igc__blade1 >> 4u;

                blade2__masked = igc__blade1 & blade2;
                //__builtin_popcount replaces commented text
                parity__2 = __builtin_popcount(blade2__masked & 0b11111110) & 1u;
                /*parity__2 = blade2__masked;
                    parity__2 ^= parity__2 >> 1u;
                    parity__2 ^= parity__2 >> 2u;
                    parity__2 ^= parity__2 >> 4u;
                    parity__2 = parity__2 & 2u;*/

                sign_of_product = 1 - 2 * parity__2;
                // sign_of_product = 1 - parity__2;
            }
        }
    }
    end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    elapsed_miliseconds = end - start;

    cout << endl;
    cout << "Calculation of entire table took " << elapsed_miliseconds.count() << " seconds to execute" << endl;

#pragma endregion benchmark

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: See [Idiomatic way of performance evaluation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60291987).  Benchmarking debug builds is basically useless, but you need to stop compilers from defeating your repeat-loops or removing computation of unused results when benchmarking optimized code. (e.g. print it after the timed region, or assign it to a `volatile` variable.)  Times like 0.0003 smell like most or all of the work got optimized away, especially if that doesn't scale with problem size if you change some constants in the source.

Comment: "I benchmark as debug" This meaningless step can be omitted.

Answer (score 0):

Following 'Peter Cordes' comment, I marked as `volatile` the variable that get the result of the computation, to stop the compiler to ignore them and jumping to the last value of the loop.

It gets more reasonable results, where the calculation costs approximately double of the table lookup, although I have no way to know what is going on under the hood, and what is the real difference in cpu time between both choices.

```
volatile int8_t sign_of_product;
```

'''
(release build output with ore repetitions)

```
Lookup table took 0.2369 seconds to execute

Lookup entire table took 1526.54 seconds to execute

Calculation took 0.5109 seconds to execute

Calculation of entire table took 3309.76 seconds to execute
```

'''

Comment: Hi, glad to know your problem has been solved! Please consider accepting it to change the thread's status to Answered.  Just a reminder :)

Comment: @Minxin Yu I don't know if I doing it correctly